# What are the system requirements of Widelands?

Tags: widelands

[Widelands](http://widelands.org/) looks like an interesting game, but I can't find the system requirements anywhere on their site. What kind of CPU and graphics card do I need?

Comment: It's free.  Why not just download it and see whether it runs acceptably on your machine?

Comment: @bwarner: I don't have the machine right now. Also, since it took half an hour to install, it would be good if this information was easily googlable.

Answer (score 1):

I can't speak to what the requirements are, but I remember playing it happily on my Dell 640m which is:

- Intel Core Duo 1.66Ghz
- 1Gb RAM
- Intel Onboard Graphics
- Ubuntu 9.10

The laptop itself is almost 4.5 years old and was fairly low budget back then.

Answer (score 0):

From [the Widelands website](https://www.widelands.org/wiki/Download/):

> Widelands will work with most any operating system, including **Windows**, **Linux**, and **MacOS**. All modern versions of these operating systems are supported, but Widelands will run on many outdated versions as well. It does not use any fancy frameworks.
>
> **At least 800 MB of RAM** are recommended for fluent gameplay; less than 300 MB will likely not work.
>
> Widelands requires a graphics card that can handle **OpenGL version 2.1 or higher**.